# I need help integrating a specific UIImage resizing extension into my current draw CGRect function

Tags: swift, swift3

I found this extension online, it allows me to have images adhere to aspect fit/fill even when drawn inside dynamically growing/shrinking image views (currently when image is saved to camera roll after my draw function the image reverts to "scale fill" regardless of what the content mode of the image view is. I suspect the reasoning for this is because I have it drawing the image to size/bounds of the image view, but since the image view is dynamic, i don't see any way around this without using this extension):

```
// MARK: - Image Scaling.
extension UIImage {


/// Scales an image to fit within a bounds with a size governed by the passed size. Also keeps the aspect ratio.
/// Switch MIN to MAX for aspect fill instead of fit.
///
/// - parameter newSize: newSize the size of the bounds the image must fit within.
///
/// - returns: a new scaled image.
func scaleImageToSize(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    var scaledImageRect = CGRect.zero

    let aspectWidth = newSize.width/size.width
    let aspectheight = newSize.height/size.height

    let aspectRatio = max(aspectWidth, aspectheight)

    scaledImageRect.size.width = size.width * aspectRatio;
    scaledImageRect.size.height = size.height * aspectRatio;
    scaledImageRect.origin.x = (newSize.width - scaledImageRect.size.width) / 2.0;
    scaledImageRect.origin.y = (newSize.height - scaledImageRect.size.height) / 2.0;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
    draw(in: scaledImageRect)
    let scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return scaledImage!
}
}
```

This is my current function I'm using for drawing the image on screen to be able to save it to camera roll (this function combines two images, a frame and an image from camera roll:

```
func drawImagesAndText() {



    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

    img = renderer.image { ctx in

   // var newSize = currentImage.scaleImageToSize


    let bgImage = currentImage
    bgImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))


    frames = UIImage(named: framesAr)
    frames?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))
    }



}
```

All the tutorials I've found on how to use extensions don't cover how to pass in and out variables like this one requires. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, that a better extension than I use. Thanks! Your problem may be that you put this in a separate target or file. Declare it as either public or open if so. Hopefully my answers yesterday helped steer you in a good direction. Good luck!

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement the extension actually. I would appreciate some direction on that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that you don't know how to use the extension, is that correct? Since it just adds a function to every UIImage, you can simply call it on your image like this: `currentImage.scaleImageToSize(newSize: someSize)` and pass the size you want the image to fit into.

Comment: can I call the "currentImage.scaleImageToSize(newSize: someSize)" once in the currentImage global declaration?  and I'm also confused on how to implement the "someSize" you described since the CGRect uses TWO points?

Comment: I appended my function to call it like you described, but I get the warning that "newSize" was never used and I'm not sure how to actually use it.                             currentImage.scaleImageToSize(newSize: someSize)
            
        currentImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imageView.bounds.size.width, height: imageView.bounds.size.height))

Comment: Hm, that doesn't make any sense to me. newSize is the parameter name used in the extension. So it looks like you don't use the extension but have your own function or override instead. I have my family over for Christmas but if you send me the full code I can take a look at it next week.

Comment: You solved it for me earlier i just didn't fully understand, please see the "answer" I posted below!

Answer (score 0):

Dorian Roy was telling me to use that call in place of using just "currentImage", and that's what worked!

(I commented on his initial answer saying I was having issues because I was trying to use the return value from the extension itself in place of "currentImage")